# React testing library - userEvent upload to input: "cannot find toLowerCase"

Tags: reactjs, testing

So i'm trying to write a simple test where i add a file to an input. Here's the element:

```
<input accept="image/*" className={classes.newPhotoInput} id="contained-button-file" type="file" name="doc" onChange={setPhoto} />
<label htmlFor="contained-button-file">
  <Button id="photo" variant="outlined" component="span">
    Загрузить новое фото
  </Button>
</label>
```

Here's the test:

```
 it('check the callbacks', async ()=>{
        const file = new File(['(⌐□_□)'], 'test.png', { type: 'image/png' });
        const wrapper = mount(<AddDefect {...props}/>);
        wrapper.find('#description').at(0).simulate('click');
        wrapper.find('#descriptionfield').at(0).find('input').at(0).simulate('change', { target: { value: 'test' } })
        const input = wrapper.find('#contained-button-file').at(0);
        
        await waitFor(()=>{
            userEvent.upload(input, file)
            //{target:{files:[file]}}
        })
        expect(input.files.length).toBe(1);
        wrapper.find('#send').at(0).simulate('click');
        expect(onSendData).toHaveBeenCalled();

        wrapper.find('#back').at(0).simulate('click');
        expect(onBack).toHaveBeenCalled();

    })
```

And here's what's going on in my package.json:

```
"jest": {
    "testEnvironment": "jsdom",
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "jsx"
    ],
    "moduleDirectories": [
      "node_modules"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga|esm)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/fileMock.js",
      "\\.(css|scss)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/styleMock.js"
    },
    "setupFilesAfterEnv": [
      "./src/setupTests.js"
    ]
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.15.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.15.6",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.14.5",
    "@testing-library/dom": "^8.11.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "enzyme": "^3.11.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.6",
    "jsdom": "18.0.1",
    "jsdom-global": "3.0.2",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.9"
  }
```

The error i get on the test:

```
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined

    Ignored nodes: comments, <script />, <style />
    <html>
      <head />
      <body />
    </html>...

      206 |         const input = wrapper.find('#contained-button-file').at(0);
      207 |         await waitFor(()=>{
    > 208 |             userEvent.upload(input, file)
          |                       ^
      209 |         })
      210 |         expect(input.files.length).toBe(1);
      211 |         wrapper.find('#send').at(0).simulate('click');

      at isElementType (node_modules/@testing-library/user-event/dist/utils/misc/isElementType.js:15:37)
      at Object.upload (node_modules/@testing-library/user-event/dist/upload.js:23:42)
      at src/Components/ViewDefects/tests/AddDefect.test.js:208:23
      at runWithExpensiveErrorDiagnosticsDisabled (node_modules/@testing-library/react/node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/config.js:50:12)
      at checkCallback (node_modules/@testing-library/react/node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/wait-for.js:136:77)
      at checkRealTimersCallback (node_modules/@testing-library/react/node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/wait-for.js:128:16)
```

I've spent past few days trying to solve the problem, and this is how far i've gotten. Googling barely helps, haven't found a single question with a problem like this. Feels like i'm missing something simple, but just can't get it yet. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got through this by using the testing library instead of enzyme, turns out enzyme isn't really suited for the material ui stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Replacing

```
userEvent.upload(input, file)
```

with

```
fireEvent.change(input, { target: { files: { item: () => file, length: 1, 0: file } },})
```

worked for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).